# gwt, rpc service, StatusCodeException, and no logs available

Tags: exception, gwt, service, rpc

sorry if my english is bad.

I have a problem while calling one of my GWT services.
On the client side, I have the following error.

```
    [ERROR] com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
    [ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
    [ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    [ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
...
```

Unhappily, I can't find any information related to this error on the server logs.
I'm in devlopment mode, and the only thing I can see in jetty is

```
 [ERROR] 500 - POST /my/maping (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
```

However, I know that my service implementation is called and that it returns a result without throwing any exception (because I use logs just before the return...) .

I have seen that this problem could be a serialization issue, but I really don't see where I miss something to make my objects serializables, ( plus, gwt compilator generally says me when something is not serializable).

And my/mapping should be finely defined, because it was working previously, and I am pretty sure that I have not modified anything related to this...

Finally, I don't find any interesting answer to my problem.
If you have any ideas, thanks in advance for your help.

ps: I use gwt 2.5.0-rc2.

Comment: Please add code snippets relevant to async call and the exception log. 500 error means most often Servlet threw an exception. Please use try catch finally to catch your exception and either log or system.out.prinln.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this can happen due to a class not have a public non-arguments constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is mostly related to a class that forgot to implement the isSerializable or Serializable interface. Also Check if all subclassess in that class also implement isSerializable or Serializable interface.

Then verify that all class have a default no argument constructor.

Comment: Not IsSerializable, but java.io.Serializable, yes. I will check in details, but it should be ok...

Comment: Sorry, it's stupid, one of my subclasses was effectively not implementing Serializable.

Comment: I also had the same problem.... my problem was  that some of my DataTransferObject class did not extend serializable

Comment: And in case somebody comes by later looking at this issue. This error is normally logged in the servlet containes log(So for tomcat it could be in $CATALINE_HOME/logs/catalina.*)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA and the class relations are setup incorrectly, a general 500 will be thrown without an specific error messages